# Android Volley ListView Images Not Loading When Using DiskBasedCache

Tags: android, listview, caching, disk, android-volley

I have an app that loads images on each item on a list view, and I use Volley to make life easier for me; I need to have to images loaded from disk if it's already been downloaded before.

**Problem:** It won't work. It needs to re-download the images all over again. I need to have the image saved even after I exit the app.

**Weird:** It works only on one particular image (and it has nothing to do with size)!

**What I Used:** I patterned this using this site: https://github.com/rdrobinson3/VolleyImageCacheExample.

I also tried this: http://howrobotswork.wordpress.com/2013/06/02/downloading-a-bitmap-asynchronously-with-volley-example/

**The Code:**

```
String godzilla = "http://vineland.pynchonwiki.com/wiki/images/c/cf/Godzilla.jpg";

//String meme = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/d7/Meme_Many_Journeys.jpg";
ImageCacheManager.getInstance().getImageLoader().get(godzilla, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer imageContainer, boolean b) {
           viewHolder.backgroundImage = imageContainer.getBitmap();
           updateBackgroundImage(viewHolder,  viewHolder.backgroundImage, object);
           updateLayoutAlignmentParams(viewHolder);
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

    }
});
if(viewHolder.backgroundImage != null)
    updateBackgroundImage(viewHolder, viewHolder.backgroundImage, object);
```

I've tried the meme website, and it still has problems. I had one particular site that contains an image that oddly works. Which makes it even more confusing.

**Edit:** Additional info, it seems like there's an error on adding lruEntries as lruEntries.remove(entry.key is being called on completeEdit().

Comment: I was doing some search about volley DiskBasedCache  and I saw your post, I am having problem with `DiskBasedCache` . I am already able to cache it in the memory, is it possible to provide a simple example of how to add memroy cache and diskbasedcache for a image ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Volley has 2 cache layers when it comes to images:

1. The L1 level: a **memory** cache *provided by you* in the `ImageLoader` constructor.
2. The L2 level: a **disk** cache that is shared among every request performed by the same `RequestQueue`.

The disk cache caches every response unless explicitly requested not to by the request. But, the caching is performed according to the **HTTP cache headers** of the response.

When you request an image, this is what Volley does:

1. Check L1 cache for image. Return if found.
2. Image not in memory - Check L2 cache. If found check expiration of the cache headers. If still valid, add to L1 cache and return image.
3. Image not on disk (either not there or expired) - Perform a network request. Cache the response in the disk cache and the bitmap in the memory cache and return.

I bet that the image that loaded from the disk has cache headers.

IMO, you have 3 options:

1. The image server is yours - add the appropriate cache headers.
2. The image server isn't yours - accept the fact the some images will not be cached on the disk.
3. Override the caching policy to better suit your needs. This means editing the Volley source code.

Comment: Oh, my God! You're amazing! That totally solved my problem! But now I think I need to have the Response object, I guess, for option 3.

Comment: Okay, last question: I'm using gradle to import the Volley library, and since I don't have direct access to the source code, I really can't modify the HttpHeaderParser.parseIgnoreCacheHeaders(), and none of my current implementation uses this. <br/><br/>

Is there a work-around for this, or do I really have to use the source and reference it as library? (As I'm a bit worried about later fixes to the libraries, and I would then need to update the whole source code) <br/><br/>
My apologies for the questions. :D

Comment: No other way as far as I have seen. If it helps, I have done it myself and so far Volley updates are seldom and very minor, so it hasn't been problematic.